# Change the Backgroundcolor in a Row if a specific Value is inside the row

Tags: c#, xaml, dataview

I have some troubles to change the color of a Row inside my Datagrid.

My Datagrid has a DataView as source. The DataView get it's values from a SQL Query. (There are several SQL Query's so the content of the DataView and it's columns are different).

Now my problem is, that I have to change the Background Color of a row if a value inside the DataView is a specific string. As example: If the value of the string is "Info" than it should be the Backgroundcolor "Blue", if the value is "Error" than it should be Red.

My DataGrid looks like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding GetDataView}"
                      Foreground="White"
                      Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyle2}"
                      RowHeaderWidth="0"
                      BorderThickness="1"
                      HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FF9A969E"
                      VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FF9A969E"
                      RowBackground="{x:Null}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      Margin="10,0,10,30"
                      Grid.Row="3"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            </DataGrid>
```

The "AutoGenereatedColumns" for the DataView are the following: 
ID, Name, Notes, Level, Date.

My problem is that I don't know to create the Trigger, so it can react to the Value of "Level" because it is autogenerated.

Answer (score 0):

You need a data trigger for a rowstyle.

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" Margin="12,12,0,0">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Level}" Value="somestring">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Something like this.

(Not tested but should work)

[More info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowstyle?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work. I don't have the property "Level" for binding because the columns of the View are Auto-Generated.